# creating a link out of variables with php

Tags: php, forms, post, input, hyperlink

I am trying create a link with variables. The variables get their content by user input which is given through html input fields.

here my html and php:

```html
        <form action="test11.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="kunde">
            <input type="text" name="nummer">
            <input type="submit" value="Erstellen">

        </form>


<?php

$fp = fopen("erstellung.html", "w");

fwrite( $fp,'<a href="placeholder"'.$_POST["kunde"].'/'.$_POST["nummer"]);

?>
```

somehow I only get the line: `"<a href="placeholder/"` in my created file "erstellung.html". The user inputs aren't getting added to the link.

All help is highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah right lol, but this won't change anything to my problem. Thanks anyways !, Edited the post

Comment: So, you're pretty much ignorant of how the `$_POST` array gets populated. If the `method` is not correct the form will default to GET, populating the `$_GET` array instead. Don't assume a small typographical error will not screw up your code. Every programmer, and I mean *every*, has run into problems because of misspellings or typos at one time or another. Welcome to the club.

Comment: well I am running into the same problem after changing it to method , thats what I was trying to say.

Comment: Then say that, instead of trying to be cute and coy. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the fwrite line to:

```html
fwrite( $fp,'<a href="placeholder'.'/'.$_POST["kunde"].'/'.$_POST["nummer"].'">'.'press'.'</a>');
```

now its working